# input isn't choosing the passwort length

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, password-manager

I'm new to programming, and I'm making a password manager.
My problem: -what it does -> when I run the program and enter the length of the password it generates a password, but it is always 4 digits long and the password gets repeated so many times as the digit I had put in.
-What it should do -> the digit that I put in should determine the length of the password and not how many times it gets repeated.

```
import random

#shuffle the list
def shuffle(string):
  tempList = list(string)
  random.shuffle(tempList)
  return ''.join(tempList)

#the password functions
uppercaseLetter=chr(random.randint(65,90))
lowercaseLetter=chr(random.randint(97,122))
punctuationSign=chr(random.randint(32,152))
digit=chr(random.randint(48,57))

#completing the password
passwordLength = int(input("choose your password length: "))

possibleChars = uppercaseLetter, lowercaseLetter, punctuationSign, digit
ranChar = shuffle(possibleChars)

tempPassword = []

count = 0
while count != passwordLength:
    tempPassword.extend(ranChar)
    count = count + 1

password = ''.join(tempPassword)

#for which sitename
sitename = input('Save under which name: ')


print (password, sitename)

data=open("test.txt",'a')
data.write(sitename +'  ')
data.write(password +'\n')
data.close()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want it to do vs what it is actually doing. Also try adding `print()` calls to announce the value of certain variables during your program to help you ensure that they are what you think they are.

Comment: There is no need for a counter. Also, if you are generating a randomized password, the length of your password will be atmost 4 i.e the number of values in the tuples you define. In this case, upperCase,LowerCase etc will generate one random value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are really over complicating what you need to do, here is what you're trying to do to the best of my knowledge

```
import random

#completing the password
passwordLength = int(input("choose your password length: "))

temp_pass = ''

count = 0
while count != passwordLength:
    char_type = random.randint(0,3)
    if char_type == 0:
        random_char = chr(random.randint(65,90))
    elif char_type == 1:
        random_char = chr(random.randint(97,122))
    elif char_type == 2:
        random_char = chr(random.randint(32,152))
    else:
        random_char = chr(random.randint(48,57))
    temp_pass = temp_pass + random_char
    count = count + 1


print(temp_pass)
```

Hope this helps. I would advise practicing the basics more before trying things like this, there is a lot of bad practises in the code.

Comment: There are bad practices here as well (particularly within the loop), and we can't be sure but I suspect that the password isn't supposed to contain only between one and four unique characters regardless of the password length.

Comment: Hi, yes I had just notice that error and fixed it, also the bad practices are from the code which I copied, hence why I stated it